# How to represent infinite matrices in Mathematica?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I asked this question on Mathematica site and the answer was basically "it is impossible". So, some math theory needs to be thrown in besides coding.

Let us represent infinite matrices as formal power series of the form

$$M=\sum _{d=-\infty }^{\infty } m_d(Y)X^d. $$

Here the function $m_d(y)$ represents the element of the matrix $M$ at the diagonal $d$ (positive diagonals are above the main diagonal) with number $y$. Each infinite matrix is uniquely defined by this two-argument function.

In other words, the infinite matrices are basically power series of the following form: $M=\sum_{d=-\infty}^\infty M_d X^d$, where $M_d$ are diaginal matrices and $X=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}  0 & 1 & 0 & . \\  0 & 0 & 1 & . \\  0 & 0 & 0 & . \\  . & . & . & . \\ \end{array} \right)$. Since any diafonal matrix can be represented as a function of $Y$: $M_d=m_d(Y)$, where $Y=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}  1 & 0 & 0 & . \\  0 & 2 & 0 & . \\  0 & 0 & 3 & . \\  . & . & . & . \\ \end{array} \right)$, we represent them as $M=\sum _{d=-\infty }^{\infty } m_d(Y)X^d$.

This way, for instance, the derivative operator in matrix form would be represented as $D=YX$, integral $\int_0^x f(t)dt$ as $Y^{-1}X^{-1}$, finite difference $\Delta=\exp(D)-1=\sum _{d=1}^{\infty } \frac{(Y X)^d}{d!}=\sum _{d=0}^{\infty } \binom{Y+d-1}{d}X^d-1=\sum _{d=1}^{\infty } \binom{Y+d-1}{d}X^d$.

The symbols $X$ and $Y$ also would represent linear operators: $X:f(x)\to\frac{f(x)}x$ and $Y:f(x)\to xf'(x)$.

That said, I wonder, whether we can define some rules that would show how a function applied to an infinite matrix transforms the kernel function $m_d(Y)$, so that we could manipulate the matrices in the form of such power series in Mathematica?

Am I correct that operations on infinite matrices can be reduced to the operations on formal power series this way?

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to interpret your definition (I don't understand the difference between $y$ and $Y$, and your definition seems to make infinite matrices [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)); but the answer to "can operations on infinite matrices be reduced to operations on formal power series?" is surely either trivially (a) yes, because that's your definition of an infinite matrix, or more interestingly (b) it depends on what operations on infinite matrices you want to perform, so that it is necessary for you to specify them before the question can be answered.

Comment: @LSpice the infinite matrices are basically power series of the following form: $M=\sum_{d=-\infty}^\infty M_d X^d$ where $M_d$ are diaginal matrices and $X=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$. Since any diafonal matrix can be represented as a function of $Y$: $M_d=m_d(Y)$ where $Y=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & . \\
 . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$, we represent them as $M=\sum _{d=-\infty }^{\infty } m_d(Y)X^d.$

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1171656), if the definitions of specific $X$ and $Y$ (as opposed to their being formal symbols) are part of the definition—I can't really tell—then they should be edited into the question.  I still don't understand what $m_d$ is, or what's the difference between $m_d(y)$ and $m_d(Y)$, but perhaps it will be obvious to anyone who can answer. Regardless, I [still](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1171651) think that you need to specify what operations you want to perform before anyone can answer whether it can be done.

Comment: @LSpice With this definition $m_d(y)$ where $y\in \mathbb N$ will give the $y$-th element on $d$-th diagonal.

Comment: @LSpice the definitions of $X$ and $Y$ are given in the question: $X:f(x)\to\frac{f(x)}x$ and $Y:f(x)\to xf'(x)$

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452959/how-to-represent-infinite-matrices-in-mathematica#comment1171659_452959), so an infinite matrix is a linear endomorphism of the space of formal power series?  Perhaps with some domain restrictions, so that $X$ makes sense?

Answer (score 7):

One particular implementation of "infinite matrices" in Mathematica is the [SNEG library](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4697), which allows for formal manipulations of [ladder operators.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator) These have matrix elements $a_{nm}=\sqrt{n+1}\delta_{n+1,m}$, $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. You can combine $a$ and its Hermitian conjugate $a^\ast$ to create more complicated infinite matrices.

Comment: This uses QM notation and the formalism looks far from general operations on infinite matrices... it would need a lot of figuring out and adaptation even if it allows the desirable.

Comment: A should note that I have Mathematica code for general operations on square (non-infinite) matrices.

Comment: In the linked article I did not find any mention of "ladder operators"...

Comment: @Anixx, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452959/how-to-represent-infinite-matrices-in-mathematica#comment1171665_452964), the ladder operators are the creation and annihilation operators first discussed on [p. 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.4697.pdf#page=3).